# PHP sum array values based on values inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

Hi I have an associative array which has common values. I want to sum those values and group based on different values.

My array is like following.

```
Array
(
    [supercategory] => Food
    [subtotal] => 1152.50
    [discount] => 10.0000
    [orderdiscount] => 10.00
    [itemdiscount] => 0.00
    [Total] => 1142.50
    [Tax] => 80.06
    [taxinclusive] => 0.00
    [taxexclusive] => 80.06
    [gratuity] => 0.00
    [totalsale] => 1222.56
)
Array
(
     [supercategory] => Drinks
    [subtotal] => 1152.50
    [discount] => 10.0000
    [orderdiscount] => 10.00
    [itemdiscount] => 0.00
    [Total] => 1142.50
    [Tax] => 80.06
    [taxinclusive] => 0.00
    [taxexclusive] => 80.06
    [gratuity] => 0.00
    [totalsale] => 1222.56
)
Array
(
     [supercategory] => Food
    [subtotal] => 1152.50
    [discount] => 10.0000
    [orderdiscount] => 10.00
    [itemdiscount] => 0.00
    [Total] => 1142.50
    [Tax] => 80.06
    [taxinclusive] => 0.00
    [taxexclusive] => 80.06
    [gratuity] => 0.00
    [totalsale] => 1222.56
)
Array
(
     [supercategory] => Alcohols
    [subtotal] => 1152.50
    [discount] => 10.0000
    [orderdiscount] => 10.00
    [itemdiscount] => 0.00
    [Total] => 1142.50
    [Tax] => 80.06
    [taxinclusive] => 0.00
    [taxexclusive] => 80.06
    [gratuity] => 0.00
    [totalsale] => 1222.56
)
```

While traversing this array I want to sum the array values within foreach loop/While based on key **supercategory** so that I can sum totalsale for all these keys having having same values.
Please help me on this.

Comment: We don't do your homework. See [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @AlexKarshin This is rude. I mean you can see I am new to Stackoverflow. You can see my previous questions where I have posted what I tried to do. But this time I am completely stuck. Basically I just need to know how can I compare previous array values with then next and then I can do SUM and make them group by my own. I mean if you can help me to initiate something then what's wrong here?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just need to know how can I compare previous array values with then next and then I can do SUM and make them group by my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about previous/next values to group your array.

Just iterate it and use the column you want to group by as a key in your result array.

```
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    $groups[$item['supercategory']][] = $item;
}
```

This will basically add a dimension to your array, where all the items are grouped under their respective `supercategory`.

After you have that structure, it's easy to do operations on groups. Here's an example of how to produce the set of sums I think you're trying to get.

```
foreach ($groups as $cat => $items) {
    $category_totals[$cat] = array_sum(array_column($items, 'totalsale'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help